# Ansible select host group dynamically

Tags: ansible

My inventory file looks like below.

```
[host-group-1]
 x.x.x.1
 x.x.x.2

[host-group-2]
 x.x.x.3
 x.x.x.4
```

Now I want to select and perform tasks on these groups based on the parameter return by a script.
The playbook looks below.

```
---
- host: 127.0.0.1
  tasks:
  - name: something 
    local_action: /home/script.py
    register: result

 - host: host-group-1:host-group-2
   task: ?????????
```

Here on the 2nd task I want something like if result== yes perform the task on host-group-1 and if result==no perform the task host-group-2

Please help me here.

Comment: Could you perhaps clarify your example? You can't apply hosts (or hostgroups) to a task, only to plays.  That is, `host` isn't a valid key on a task (nor is `task`, for that matter).  If you could include a more concrete description of what you're trying to do that would also help, because there may be a solution other than what you're describing.

Comment: @larsks the requirement is simple I want to choose the host groups based on the parameter returned by a script.

Comment: That's not "simple", and your example is not clear. If you can show, using valid anisble syntax, what behavior you would like it would be easier to provide an answer.

Comment: Did you simply try `- hosts: "{{ hostvars['127.0.0.1'].result.stdout == 'yes' | ternary('host-group-1', 'host-group-2')}}"`? (I agree that you example is really bad has is not valid ansible code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following example shows how to use Jinja in a playbook. Most people use only Jinja expressions `{{ ... }}`. But if you need to do more complicate tasks, it is also possible to use Jinja statements `{% ... %}`. But a statement has no return value. So you have to end with an expression, if you want to return a value to the `set_fact` task.

```
---
- name: Get group
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - shell: |-
        echo {{ say }}
      register: group
      ignore_errors: true
      changed_when: false
    - set_fact:
        group: >-
          {% if group.stdout == "yes"     -%}
          {%   set group = "host-group-1" -%}
          {% elif group.stdout == "no"    -%}
          {%   set group = "host-group-2" -%}
          {% else                         -%}
          {%   set group = ""             -%}
          {% endif                        -%}
          {{ group }}

- hosts: "{{ hostvars.localhost.group }}"
  tasks:
    - debug: var=group
```

If you run the playbook with `yes` it used the first group. The debug action is skipped, because I have not specified an inventory file.

```
$ ansible-playbook if.yml --extra-vars say=yes

PLAY [Get group] *****************************************************************************

TASK [command] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY [host-group-1] **************************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

And if you run it with `no` it uses the second group.

```
$ ansible-playbook if.yml --extra-vars say=no

PLAY [Get group] *****************************************************************************

TASK [command] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY [host-group-2] **************************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Some hints about shell scripts:

- Whenever the return value of a shell script is not zero, Ansible treats this as an error. This breaks your Ansible run. If you want to handle any error in your Ansible code your have to ignore the error with `ignore_errors: true`.
- Each shell script is treated as change, because Ansible has no understand, what the shell code does. And because it might change something, Ansible treats it always as a change. If you just collect information on your local host, this is no change at all. So it is necessary to tell Ansible that the code does not change anything with `changed_when: false`.

A hint how Ansible stores information:

Ansible's internal data structure is one big messy global variable, which is called `hostvars`. Ansible has virtually no kind of scope, which makes nested loops challenging (but this is another topic). All results of tasks are stored in this single global monster hash variable with the name of the host as a key. Whatever you run on `localhost` is stored in `hostvars.localhost`. Every host has full access to the data of each other host. This makes it possible to collect information in localhost to use it later in the task working on other hosts.

btw. I have no idea, why you got so many down votes. I think this is not a trivial question.

Comment: Perfect answer. Even I didn't understand why I got so many downvote

Comment: This helped me in a different context: Pick the hostname from an inventory where the path in the YAML file is determined by a parameter passed to the ansible script.